# Ruby method to round a floating number frandomly when fractional component is 0.5

Tags: ruby

I am working on a statistical problem and need to round randomly up or down if the fractional component is 0.5. The following code should work

```
def round_random(x)
    return x.round unless x.modulo(1) == 0.5
    x.floor + rand(2)
end
```

but I recall some discussion about doing this in ruby, so I wonder if there is actually a standard method for it.

Comment: Do you mean "fractional" rather than "factional"?

Comment: I did mean fractional rather than factional, I must have been reading too much political commentary. I have edited accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.4, [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Float.html#method-i-round) takes an optional keyword argument `half` to specify the round mode for *"[...] numbers that are half-way between two possible rounded values"*

Your method would become:

```
def round_random(x)
  x.round(half: [:up, :down].sample)
end

round_random(2.6) #=> 3 (always)

round_random(2.5) #=> 2
round_random(2.5) #=> 3
round_random(2.5) #=> 2

round_random(2.4) #=> 2 (always)
```

There's also `:even` which implements [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) – a rule to avoid bias by rounding to the next *even* number in case of a tie:

```
1.5.round(half: :even) #=> 2
2.5.round(half: :even) #=> 2
3.5.round(half: :even) #=> 4
4.5.round(half: :even) #=> 4
```

Maybe that would be a more deterministic alternativ to your problem.

Comment: This answer will fulfill the purpose, but I think the original intention of the feature was to simply use the `:even` option in cases like this, which will "round half toward the nearest even number", which will, in a long run, give the same result without actually returning random results. And I think this is actually what the OP is mentioning.